# How to select an item from json data with ngResource?

Tags: html, json, angularjs, ngresource

I'm trying to select data from my json file with
**$resource** request :

Im using a global variable **productSelected** in my controller,

but when I change it's value with ng-model , that don't do an effect on the model and the value of reference still the same!

Anyone have an idea please ?

Here is my code :

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

            myApp.factory('Produits',['$resource', function ($resource) {
                return $resource('data/produits.json/:id',{id: "@id"},
                         {
                     'get':    {method:'GET'},
                     'save':   {method:'POST'},
                     'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
                     'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
                     'delete': {method:'DELETE'}

                         }
                );
            }]);
    myApp.controller('produitsCtrl', function($scope, $http,Produits,$log) {

     $scope.productSelected=0;

                 Produits.query(function(data){ 
                     $scope.produits=data; 
                     $scope.reference=$scope.produits[$scope.productSelected].reference ;
                     });

      });
        <div ng-app="myApp" >

                <div ng-controller="produitsCtrl"> 

                Product : <input type="text" ng-model="productSelected"/> {{ productSelected }} <br/>
                Reference : {{reference}}
                </div>
            </div>
```

**produits.json**

```
[{
"id" : 1,
"reference": "AA"
},
{
"id" : 2,
"reference": "BB"
}]
```

Comment: May be because your Produits.query is getting called only once even after changing the value of $scope.productSelected using input text box.So I think you have to call Produits.query every time when ever there is change in productSelected value.

Comment: Is there other solution to avoid calling query, every time, because I have many properties for items (id, reference, name, type..etc)

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at this code may be helpful for you

```
<body ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl" id="div1">
 Product : <input type="text" ng-model="productSelected" ng-change="fun(productSelected)"/> {{ productSelected }} <br/>

 Reference :<p ng-model="reference"> {{reference}} </p>


 <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){


    $scope.productSelected=0;
    $scope.produits= [{
            "id" : 1,
            "reference": "AA"
            },
            {
            "id" : 2,
            "reference": "BB"
            }];
     $scope.reference=$scope.produits[$scope.productSelected].reference;
   $scope.fun=function(val){
    //alert(val)
     if(val!=undefined && val!=null && val!='')
    $scope.reference=$scope.produits[$scope.productSelected].reference;
    else
     $scope.reference=$scope.produits[0].reference; 
   };
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thks a lot, but here you dont use _ngResource_  service to inject **Produits** in the controller, I was searching how to optimize my code.